# Установка свойства закрытого вложенного класса методами рефлексии

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Имеется сборка Windows Forms. Она включает одну форму на которой есть private TextBox.
Возможно ли методами рефлексии загрузить эту сборку и установить у TextBox свойство Text?

```
Assembly library = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Test.exe");
Type type = library.GetType("WindowsFormsApp.Test");

dynamic form = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
FieldInfo textBox = form.GetType().GetField("tbTest", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
PropertyInfo textBoxText = textBox.FieldType.GetProperty("Text", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

// ... недоступен из-за его уровня защиты
textBoxText.SetValue(form.tbTest, "Строка");
```

Comment: А зачем вам такие сложности, и почему они возникли?

Comment: @Monomax исследую направления тестирования сборок .NET, как чёрного ящика

Comment: @dantt3 судя по определению, когда тестируется "черный ящик", тестировщик не должен ничего знать о внутреннем устройстве модуля. Тестируется только внешняя функциональность.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko а я ничего и не знаю о внутреннем устройстве модуля. Рефлексия в данном случае нужна для получения базовой информации о контролах с которыми я буду работать. Вот в данном вопросе я рассматриваю проблему отправки текста в textbox стороннего приложения. Знаю, что задача решается через WinAPI с применением скажем sendmessage; теперь пытаюсь понять, можно ли провернуть похожий трюк методами рефлексии

Comment: @dantt3, очень странным делом вы занимаетесь. Как уже сказал AndreiKhotko , тестировать необходимо только внешнюю функциональность. Если разработчик стороннего приложения сделал какое либо свойство приватным, значит он подразумевал, что управлять его состоянием будет только класс, в котором он определен. Да и вообще, такие тесты(я предполагаю вы пишете Unit тесты) не стабильны. У вас имеется внешняя зависимость, в данном случае внешнее приложение, которое вы даже не сможете замокать. Почитайте о том, как лучше писать Unit тесты, на Pluralsight ест отличные курсы)

Comment: @ValeryLosev действительно странным, тут не поспоришь. Я пока исследую возможности взаимодействия со сторонними приложениями, будь то рефлексия или winapi. И нет, юнит тесты я писать не планирую, они прекрасно реализованы на уровне самой visual studio. Планируется скорее некое динамическое тестирование

Comment: Ничего не зная о сборке, вы не можете её протестировать просто загрузив её в память. Если вы озадачились тестированием настольного приложения, вам надо иметь возможность его запустить и тыкать по нему как будто это делает реальный юзер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

```
object tb = tbTest.GetValue(form);
MethodInfo setter = textBoxText.GetSetMethod(nonPublic: true);
setter.Invoke(tb, new object[] { "Строка" });
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить значение нужного `textBox` - т.е. объект типа `TextBox`. Если я вас правильно понимаю, то вот код ниже:

```
var library = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Test.exe");

var type = library.GetType("WindowsFormsApp.Test");

var form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var textBoxField = form.GetType().GetField("textBox1", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

var textBoxInstance = (TextBox)textBoxField.GetValue(form);

textBoxInstance.Text = "Строка";
```

Comment: Спасибо, за ваш ответ, но приведение типов не допустимо. Может использоваться сторонний контрол, о котором не известно на момент компиляции моего кода. В вопросе я абстрактно использовал TextBox, чтобы обозначить проблему и вероятно, ввёл вас в заблуждение.
Решил проблему самостоятельно, за минуту до вашего ответа

Comment: @dantt3 если вы работаете в области тестирования, то крайне рекомендую почитать pdf-книжки одного автора, который работает с тестированием всю жизнь и является одним из лучших специалистов в этой области. Если интересно, [вот ссылка](https://svyatoslav.biz/software_testing_book/).